# Java : How to avoid hand-shake mode with HttpURLConnection authentication?

Tags: java, web-services, http, url, authentication

I am calling a REST Web Service with HttpURLConnection like so (this is not the actual URL and credentials, of course I changed the values before posting on a public forum)...

```
        String uri = "http://99.82.36.238:8443/media/crowd?";
        String query = String.format("office_code=%s&content_type_code=%s", 
                URLEncoder.encode("USA"), URLEncoder.encode("SGV"));

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/xml");

        String username = "userNewbie";
        String password = "password";
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",   CredentialsEncoder.userNamePasswordBase64(username,password));

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode() + " because " + conn.getResponseMessage());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));
```

The problem is that the service that I am calling does not work in a hand-shake mode. Meaning it needs me to send the creds the first time the request is made, rather than making the request and getting the 403 and then sending the cred.

Can anyone suggest how to modify the above code to meet that requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: Meaning that the server isn't configured correctly. You can't solve a server-side problem from the client, at least not this one, with this code.

Comment: When are you calling `conn.connect()`?  If it's after you set the authentication properties, they should be sent in the initial GET request.

Comment: I am not actually calling conn.connect, here is the rest of my code..

Comment: Warren, Are you certain that the auth creds are being in the initial GET request?

Comment: EJP, even if the server is misconfigured I need to send the creds with the initial GET request. Surely there must be a way to do it with the client side code. Thanks!